# Allow flagging of deleted posts as rude and abusive

Tags: feature-request, flags, offensive

Currently, it's not possible to flag a deleted post as rude and abusive.

A post with 6 rude and abusive flags causes the owner to lose 100 rep, as well as having their question deleted. By contrast, if their question is downvoted and then deleted, they don't face a similar level of reputation loss - for example, the user who posted this [hateful post](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/29907/270), which was deleted by the community via delete votes (and see that poster's comment as well, in case you're in any doubt), has not lost a single reputation point, and is on exactly 101 reputation despite not having any other source of reputation.

Being able to flag a deleted post as rude and abusive also means that the contents can be hidden from high rep users unless they actively choose to see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still use custom moderator flags on deleted posts. This has the advantage that ♦ moderators will be aware of the problematic behaviour of this user, and can choose to suspend them for a while, which is sometimes more effective than an IP block and/or reputation loss.

Otherwise, this is a good reason not to cast delete votes on rude/abusive posts.

---

> Being able to flag a deleted post as rude and abusive also means that the contents can be hidden from high rep users unless they actively choose to see it.

A post which has at least **one** spam/rude/abusive flag on it when it is deleted will have its contents hidden behind a revision link. It doesn't need six flags for that, and whether it's deleted by a ♦ moderator, three trusted users or red flags doesn't matter either.

Comment: I'm right that you, as moderator, can also make content hidden after the fact, right?

Comment: By undeleting and red-flagging the post (or by editing the post). There's no 'hide contents' option in the mod menu.

Comment: Ah, okay, I assumed there was a menu option. Thanks

Comment: @rene nah, why bother adding such very-very-rarely-used option? Maybe Shog got it as some magic button, but ordinary mods don't have those fancy things. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308444/162102) says, you can use a custom flag to make moderators aware of the situation, and moderators can take actions on both the post and the user.

If the system were to allow red-flagging deleted posts, it would be important to have some sort of exception for *self-deleted* posts.  If somebody makes an offensive post, realizes it, and *takes corrective action*, then we shouldn't penalize him with a rep hit.  First off, it feels like we're punishing him after he fixed the problem, and second, it could discourage self-moderation like that.  ("Eh, won't make a difference, so I might as well leave my rant here.")

I think this is enough of an edge case that we don't need to change how flags work.  But if we were to, we'd have to exclude this case.  Once you're into rare special cases of rare special cases, it's probably better to leave it alone and let moderators be exception-handlers.